# ARMA fitted value without historical(lag) data

Tags: r, sas, prediction, forecast

lets say I have a ARMA(2,2) model, which require lag terms of t-1 and t-2,
what will my fitted value be for first (where lag terms of both t-1 and t-2 is missing) and second (where lag terms of t-2 is missing) time position?

Observed that SAS is using the below formula (please correct me if I am wrong):

First fitted value : y1 = constant
Second fitted value : y2 =constant + AR(1)y1 + MA(1)e1
Third fitted value : y3 = constant + AR(1)y1 + AR(2)y2 + MA(1)e1 + MA(2)e2 (which is the full formula)
where AR(x) and MA(x) is the coefficient for AR and MA terms.

Observed that ARMA model from R is using different method (which I could not decipher yet).
But I could not find any proper documentation to support on how should the first few fitted value be computed.

**Could anyone advise if there is any research/proofs/guidance/publication available to show the appropriate method to compute the first few fitted value of an ARMA model?**

I am still new to this space and this is my first time posting question. Many apologies if there is any lacking in information, and please feel free to post your queries and I will update further.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[R uses MLE estimation by default](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html), whereas [SAS uses conditional lease squares](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/etscdc/14.2/etsug/etsug_arima_syntax05.htm). You can change this in PROC ARIMA with the `method=ml` option in the `estimate` statement. Your two models should produce identical estimates. It's generally recommended to always use `method=ml` in SAS.

```
proc arima data=have;
    identify var=foo;
    estimate p=2 q=2 method=ml;
    forecast lead=2;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information! After further reading, noted that SAS is estimating the first few values as per my observation (formulas in my questions), documented as below:
"unobserved past values of xt are set to 0 and � are computed from the estimates of AR(x) and MA(x) at each iteration.
For METHOD=ULS and METHOD=ML, initial estimates are computed using the METHOD=CLS algorithm." --- from SAS link you shared, thanks!

However, I have yet to understand on how is R computing first few estimate when there is unobserved past values. By chance would you be able to share further?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have much further information on what R is doing.

Comment: No worries, thank you Stu for your assistance.
Believe that SAS is using this methodology "unobserved past values of xt are set to 0" basing on some research. By any chance, hopefully anyone / SAS personnel could further advise on the proof/research to back the methodology used. Thanks!

Comment: Just some additional information, I was looking into what R does when you use CSS (unsure if it's exactly the same as CLS) and it also unobserved past values to 0. I am unable to find any formal research on this subject.